# SAS to SQL Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

As a SQL developer looking at SAS code for the first time, I'm struggling to understand a section of a script I've been provided.

Please could anybody explain what the following does, or if possible, the equivalent in SQL?

```
* sum up the total 6 months value for customers with positive value and quantity of items;

proc summary data=value_last6_positive nway missing;
    var saleprice quantity;
    class Cardid  ;
        output out = value_last6_s (drop=_type_ _freq_)
            sum(saleprice)=saleprice
            sum(quantity)=quantity;
    run;

* rank them;

proc sort data=value_last6_s;
    by saleprice;
    run;

data count;
    set value_last6_s;
    count=1;
    run;

proc sort data=count;
    by count;
    run;

data count2;
    set count;
    by count;
    if first.count then rank=1;
    else rank+1;

    if rank=<544139 then decile=10;
    else if rank=<544139*2 then decile=9;
    else if rank=<544139*3 then decile=8;
    else if rank=<544139*4 then decile=7;
    else if rank=<544139*5 then decile=6;
    else if rank=<544139*6 then decile=5;
    else if rank=<544139*7 then decile=4;
    else if rank=<544139*8 then decile=3;
    else if rank=<544139*9 then decile=2;
    else decile=1;

run;

proc freq data=count2;
    table decile;
    run;

proc means data=count2;
var saleprice;
    class decile;
    run;
```

I've got as far as constructing a temp table equivalent of `value_last6_s` which has the structure `(CardID, SalePrice, Quantity)` using an aggregation of sales data grouped by `CardID`. Not really sure how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*

My conversion of the first `proc summary` block:

```
-- value_last6_s
SELECT  CardID,
        SUM(SalePrice) SalePrice,
        SUM(Quantity) Quantity
INTO    #value_last6_s
FROM    #value_last6_positive
GROUP BY CardID
ORDER BY SUM(SalePrice);
```

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think it sums up the total 6 months value for customers with positive value and quantity of items...

Comment: @RQDQ Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't resist. :-) What SQL have you developed so far?

Comment: I've converted up to the start of the snippet, including the `proc summary` block. I'll include that in the question.

Comment: I am not sure the SAS code is correct or does what it should be intended to... Any idea on functional requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first steps are just creating a summary table.  The dummy variable COUNT is added as a constant, which you probably do not need. The sorting is needed to get the values in order of the sum or SALEPRICE so that the RANK variable can be created in the next step.

```
create table COUNT as
  select Cardid
      , sum(saleprice) as saleprice
      , sum(quantity) as quantity
  from value_last6_positive 
  group by Cardid
;
```

The next data step is generating a RANK variable.  You cannot do that in PROC SQL since it does not include windowing functions.  You should be able to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to do that. You can replace the IF/THEN/ELSE chain with a CASE statement.

```
create table COUNT2 as 
 select a.* 
      , row_number() over (order by saleprice) as RANK
      , case 
        when (rank<=544139) then 10
        when (rand<=544139*2) then 9
        ...
        else 1 end as DECILE
  from COUNT a
;
```

The final steps are creating reports using the new DECILE variable.

So a frequency report.

```
select decile,count(*) as COUNT,COUNT/(count(*) over()) as PERCENT
  from count2
  group by 1
  order by 1
;
```

And a summary of the means.

```
select decile
     , count(saleprice) as N
     , mean(saleprice) as Mean
     , min(saleprice) as Min
     , max(saleprice) as Max
from count2
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't your suggested improvement identical to my conversion but with the added `1` constant column? I'm dumping into a temp table so I can break each section of the script down step by step. I don't really have an issue with this bit, it's the later ranking by a constant and decile interpretation that I don't understand.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you going to use? Does it have a RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() function that you could use to replace the sum statement that the data step uses to calculate the rank?

Comment: T-SQL, so yes - `RANK() OVER...`

Comment: Great, so use RANK() and order by saleprice. Use a CASE statement to replace the series of IF/THEN statements.

Comment: @Tom `select into` in SQL Server does make a table (as it can in SAS, actually, as well).

Comment: I was getting confused by the addition of the constant value for count then sorting by it, which I think is an unneeded step. I'm pretty sure your answer covers the intention of the script so marking as resolved! Thanks.